# how can i perform a click event using firefox with python and selenium?

Tags: python, mouseevent, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm new in selenium. I'm trying to simulate a click event on a page element. If I do this by left clicking in the browser I get a new page: my need is to obtain the same result with a python program using selenium.

Using Firefox inspector I have identified the element and highlighted the linked event:

[Firefox Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKiX7.png)

So in my python program I have inserted the statement:

```
tasto = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"crypto-coins-table_loadMoreText___l12V")
```

that returns no error. If I execute tasto.click() python raises an elementNonInteractableException.

How can I command Firefox with selenium so that the click event is executed?